# 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working on some type of countdown application:

```
datac=datetime.datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d') #im stuck on this line
```

Here is the error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to achieve and what you have tried (with code and reproducible examples).

Answer (score 1):

If using `from datetime import datetime` to import datetime, you can remove the extra `datetime` in your code, like this:

```
datac=datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Or you can change your datetime import to this:

```
import datetime
```

Comment: Or if their import is `from datetime import datetime` change that to be `import datetime` instead...

Answer (score 1):

You can fix your issue by using of two ways.

1. change "from datetime import datetime" to "import datetime"

or

2. change "datac=datetime.datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')" to "datac=datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')"

Answer (score 0):

Just use as follows

```
import datetime from datetime
datetime.strptime(data, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

`strptime` is a method of `datetime.datetime` not `datetime`.